# How to get router at url to edit css in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm Using asp.net MVC, now i have a problem with router.
[image]

I have 4 link in nav like this, each link have each router. If i click to each link, i want to highlight it, or make it different (be choose).
My idea is get url router and go to view to change. But i didn't know how to get url link at this time in Pages.
Anyone has idea or show me how can do it easierly

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be using CSS for styling links. Here's the website that should [help](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp):